# UICollectionView cells allign horizontally instead of vertically to mimmick springboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my collection view im trying to mimmick the iphone 5 app springboard (4 apps in a horizontal row and 5 rows) to display my apps. I currently have 5 cells (planning on about 25 cells or so) and the collection view is set to scroll horizontally with paging enabled which works but when i add cells with this method:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return apps.count; //currently 5
}
```

they align vertically so instead of horizontally, how can i make it so the align horizontally?

Here's a sketch

Whats happening:

```
cell

cell

cell

cell

cell
```

What I want to happen:

```
cell cell cell cell

cell
```

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a UICollectionViewLayout.  [Here's a great tutorial](http://www.skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial).

Comment: the link is broken or no longer valid.